# SwiftUI NavigationBar Focus

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do I replicate `UIKit` becomeFirstResponder behavior with [searchable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/searchable(text:placement:)) in `SwiftUI` component. The search bar appears on the navigation bar and the keyboard should show up as soon as view appears.

```
.searchable(text: $fetchData.searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always), prompt: "Search")
```

Comment: Do you want a replicated version of SwiftUI in **UIKIT**? Or?

Comment: in `SwiftUI` for above mentioned code.